# app crashes in release build on using react-native-video-processing ProcessingManager

Tags: android, react-native, crash, react-native-video

```
 ProcessingManager.getVideoInfo('file://' + path).then(data => {
            const {size} = data;
            const {height, width} = size;
            const ratio = width / height;
          const options = {
            width: 720,
            height: 720,
            bitrateMultiplier: 3,
            minimumBitrate: 700000,
          };
          ProcessingManager.compress('file://' + path, options) // like VideoPlayer trim options
            .then(data => {
              RNFetchBlob.fs.stat(data.source).then(stats => {
                const {path} = stats;
                ProcessingManager.trim(path, {
                  startTime: 0,
                  endTime: 60,
                }) // like VideoPlayer trim options
                  .then(data => {
                    navigation.navigate('AddVideo', {
                      id: userId,
                      items: [data],
                      type: 'user',
                      ratio,
                    });
                  });
              });
            });
          });
```

is the code
after selecting image from gallery path is extracted from from info and used here as shown in above.
when we reach to code as run time, app got crashes only in release build.

```
 Background concurrent copying GC freed 655389(26MB) AllocSpace objects, 88(9760KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 11MB/23MB, paused 95us,40us total 100.848ms
09-05 09:19:23.736 25101 25101 E com.x.x: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x40000000
09-05 09:19:23.736 25101 25101 I com.x.x: Using CollectorTypeCC GC.
09-05 09:19:23.740 25101 25101 E com.x.x: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
09-05 09:19:23.748 25101 25120 E com.x.x: Could not write anonymous vdex /system/framework/oat/arm64/mediatek-framework.vdex: Could not open /system/framework/oat/arm64/mediatek-framework.vdex for writing
```

is logcat error